# Spring junit autowired custom class must have constructor itself?

Tags: java, spring, junit, constructor, autowired

I'm new to Spring framework. I got a question when trying to write spring integration test.

I got this animal class.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "animal")
public class Animal {
    private Cat cat;

    /*public Animal(Cat cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }*/

    public Cat getCat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public static class Cat {

        @Value("${leg}")
        private String leg;

        public String getLeg() {
            return leg;
        }
    } 
}
```

And my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@TestPropertySource("classpath:../classes/conf/animal.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(classes={Animal.class, Animal.Cat.class})

public class AnimalTest {

    @Autowired
    Animal animal;

    @Test
    public void testAnimal(){
        System.out.println("animal.cat.leg : " + animal.getCat().getLeg());
        Assert.assertEquals("four", animal.getCat().getLeg());
    }
}
```

And here is my yaml file content

```
animal:
    cat: 
        leg: four
```

I get this error which spring framework fail to read my yaml file content correctly.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.openet.tsb.AnimalTest.testAnimal(AnimalTest.java:41)
```

The test will pass after I uncomment out my Animal constructor.

So my question is,

1. The constructor is necessary?
2. Is there another way to skip constructor and autowired the variable name match to name in yaml file?
3. If constructor necessary, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring don't know where and how to build the `Cat` object inside the `Animal` constructor, you need to define also a default constructor for spring

you can also `@Autowired` the `Cat` inside the `Animal` class and spring will know how to build `Animal` (like you did in test class) in this case the constructor is not necessary

```
public class Animal {
    @Autowired
    private Cat cat;

    public Cat getCat() {
        return cat;
    }
....
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work when I changed Cat to List<Cat>. My yaml file look like this now: 

animal:
    cat: 
        - leg: four
        - leg: three